# jQuery UI Multiselect does not render items in the order saved in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I'm using jQuery UI Multiselect plugin: http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/. When I select items and save them to a database, I also keep track of their order and save it in the database, too. When I load the items (of course I order them in my query by their order values), they are set as selected but the plugin orders them not by the order I want but in its own way. Since the plugin is applied over a `<select><option value="ID of the item"></option></select>` elements I know that it uses `<option>` values (the IDs from database) to handle ordering. I've been looking in the documentation, but could not find anything to guide me further. I'd be very grateful if anyone has any idea or has encountered this problem before and solved it, to help me.